# Can we start sentence with direct object? with or without comma?

Tags: grammar

"What you dream of achieving, you have to first bury and forget before you start working on it."

Is this sentence grammatically correct with direct object at the beginning? also, do we need comma or not?

thx

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Good. No comma. What you see is what you get. :)

Comment: In your case, and for *Whom the gods would destroy* (@Malvolio), they are both *WH-* clauses serving as the object of the next clause. But you can't say: *The ball, I threw*. Instead, it would have to be *I threw the ball* (normal word order) or *I, the ball, threw* (weird word order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Whom the gods would destroy, they first make mad."
>   -- Henry Wadsworth Longfellow

So, yes, you can do it -- it comes out sounding poetic, for better or worse -- and yes, you need a comma.

(*Mad* here is used in the sense of "insane".)